# Как сделать фильтрацию данных в DataGridView в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

Есть `ComboBox` с данными коллекции департаментов. Есть `DataGridView` с данными коллекции рабочих. Нужно, чтобы при выборе департамента в `ComboBox`, `DataGridView` отображал только тех рабочих, которые работают в данном департаменте. `Department(int id, string name)`  `Worker(string name, int age, int departmentId)`
Вот такой код видел, но он не работает, в `DataGridView` всегда пусто

```
private void cbDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvWorkers.DataSource = data.workersDB.Where(find);
}
    
private bool find(Worker a)
{
    return a.DepartmentId == ((Department)cbDepartments.SelectedItem).Id;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource

Answer (score 0):

Получилось через FindAll

```
private void cbDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvWorkers.DataSource = data.workersDB.FindAll(find);
}
    
private bool find(Worker a)
{
    return a.DepartmentId == ((Department)cbDepartments.SelectedItem).Id;
}
```